# How do you add new objects to a user-defined Class vector?

Tags: c++, vector, push-back

I'm a C++ beginner (no prior programming experience). I'm writing a text-based game and I have a core module to develop for the "Population" of the game. So far I've established the population growth rates (based on pre-defined natality and mortality rates) and what I'm seeking to do now is to create a unique object for each citizen.

I've created the **Citizen** class, and I use a vector to generate the initial population of citizens:

```
vector<Citizen> myCitizens (100);
```

There is a function that sets several initial values for each of these 100 citizens. No problems there.

Every "year" the program calculates the births and deaths for that year. I want to add new objects to the **myCitizens** vector based on the number of births for that year.

I'm stuck on this function:

Declaration:

```
int new_citizens(int newBirths);
```

Definition:

```
int new_citizens(int newBirths)
{
myCitizens.push_back(newBirths);
}
```

Compiler build messages:

```
error: no matching function for call to 'std::vector<Citizen>::push_back(int&)'
note: candidate is:
note: void std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::push_back(const value_type&) [with _Tp = Citizen;  _Alloc = std::allocator<Citizen>; std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::value_type = Citizen]
```

I've searched for the issue, looked at docs, messed around with changing the types to no avail. I've compiled examples where push_back did work. I think I'm missing a fundamental piece of the puzzle when it comes to creating *class* objects through a vector.

My current hypothesis at the time is that I'm declaring type information wrong or not correctly passing information to the vector. I'm going to keep trying. Any pointers in the right direction would be appreciated!

Thank you,

Optimae

Comment: You're adding a int type to a vector of citizens, if citizens has a constructor that takes int, use emplace.

Comment: Are you *trying* to add an `int` to your vector? Or is your intent to *expand* the vector by some N number of entries?

Comment: @WhozCraig, After reading the question more thoroughly, I think the latter.

Comment: @chris I concur with that assessment. An interesting take on it as well. It never occurred to me that one may conceive that as the method for expansion, and yet, I totally now see how that path was taken.

Comment: @WhozCraig Yes, my intention is to _expand_ the vector (the population) by N number (new births).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
vector<Citizen> myCitizens (100);
```

this defines a `vector` named `myCitizens` comprised of 100 objects of `Citizen` class, and each of them is initialized with `Citizen()`. Then if I correctly get that what you want to do is to resize vector to contain total number of `newBirths` of `Citizen` objects you can do it this way:

```
int new_citizens(int newBirths)
{
    // first we need to remove items, after this size() is 0
    myCitizens.clear();

    // and populate vector now
    for(unsigned int i = 0; i<newBirths; i++)
        myCitizens.push_back(Citizen());
}
```

you can also use [`std::vector::resize`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/resize) to achieve this:

```
int new_citizens(int newBirths){
    myCitizens.resize(newBirths);
}
```

note:
using  `resize` the size of container is adjusted to be exactly what you specify in call to this function: container size will be reduced if current size is greater than what you specified in call to `resize` or increased if current size is less than `newBirths`.

if however you want to **add** this number of new items to an existing vector, then you can do it this way:

```
int new_citizens(int newBirths)
{
    // just add new items
    for(unsigned int i = 0; i<newBirths; i++)
        myCitizens.push_back(Citizen());
}
```

or again, using resize:

```
int new_citizens(int newBirths){
    myCitizens.resize(myCitizens.size() + newBirths);
}
```

Comment: Your beginning paragraph clarified what I was doing wrong, and yes, the last paragraph (_adding_ new items to an existing vector) contains the answer I was looking for. Resize is definitely a more elegant way. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You defined your vector to hold objects of class Citizen

```
vector<Citizen>
```

Function push_back() accepts objects of type value_type, that is Citizen in your case.

```
void push_back (const value_type& val);
```

You could pass a number in a constructor

```
vector<Citizen> myCitizens (100);
```

because there is a constructor that accepts numbers:

```
explicit vector (size_type n, const value_type& val = value_type(),
                 const allocator_type& alloc = allocator_type());
```

To make your function work you could write a loop instead:

```
for (int i = 0; i < newBirths; ++i)
{
    myCitizens.push_back(Citizen());
}
```

As [chris](https://stackoverflow.com/users/962089/chris) noted you may use resize() function. In fact, that would be more elegant than the loop.

```
myCitizens.resize(myCitizens.size() + newBirths)
```

See [std::vector resize()](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/resize)

Comment: why in the heap? who will release these memory?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add newBirths news citizens, then do a loop, like this one

```
int new_citizens(int newBirths)
{
    for(unsigned int it = 0; it<newBirths; ++it)
        myCitizens.push_back(Citizen()); // <-- uses the default constructor
}
```